custom date format in journal event panel
We'd like to have other date format in journal events panel.
How to do it?
Format date actuator respond as yyyy-MM-ddThh:mi:ss
we'd like to have dd/MM/yyyy hh:mi:ss in journal panel
Actually we did not try any solution so please help
